# Different price between yf.download and yf.Ticker

Tags: python, yfinance

I am extracting the opening price of a stock, say "AAPL"(Apple Inc) using `yfinance`. I come across something very interesting, yet confusing details. I have used two methods to obtain the opening price of the stock, `yf.Ticker` and `yf.download`.

```
apple1 = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
apple2 = yf.download("AAPL")
```

As you can see in the dataframe below, the opening price for both methods shows totally different prices. Any idea what's happening here?

```
hist = apple1.history(period="max")
hist["Open"][:100]
Out[97]: 
Date
1980-12-12    0.100323
1980-12-15    0.095525
1980-12-16    0.088546
1980-12-17    0.090291
1980-12-18    0.092908
  
1981-04-30    0.099015
1981-05-01    0.099015
1981-05-04    0.099015
1981-05-05    0.098578
1981-05-06    0.095962
Name: Open, Length: 100, dtype: float64
```

```
apple2["Open"][:100]
Out[98]: 
Date
1980-12-12    0.128348
1980-12-15    0.122210
1980-12-16    0.113281
1980-12-17    0.115513
1980-12-18    0.118862
  
1981-04-30    0.126674
1981-05-01    0.126674
1981-05-04    0.126674
1981-05-05    0.126116
1981-05-06    0.122768
Name: Open, Length: 100, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I tried my same thing. The result was the same as yours. I took the difference between the two sides and there was no difference from 2022-02-04.

Comment: Yes, that's why this is unusual. If the data is inconsistent before 2022-02-04, it'd be hard to tell which to use

Comment: It's the same for all the stocks apparently

Comment: My earlier comment was incorrect, I checked with TSLA and the two sets of data were identical, there may be something wrong with the APPL issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`history()`](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/main/yfinance/base.py) allows you to set the `auto_adjust=False` parameter, which deactivates adjustments on OHLC (Open/High/Low/Close prices). By default, adjustments are enabled.

For [`download()`](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/main/yfinance/multi.py) adjustments are disabled by default.

If disabled for `history()`, both variants lead to the same result:

```
hist = apple1.history(period="max", auto_adjust=False)
hist["Open"][:100]

apple2 = yf.download("AAPL")
apple2["Open"][:100]
```

Equally, `auto_adjust` can also be enabled for `download()`. Which then yields the same (adjusted) results.

```
hist = apple1.history(period="max")
hist["Open"][:100]
apple2 = yf.download("AAPL", auto_adjust=True)
apple2["Open"][:100]
```